# How to save my python file in a particular folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath

I want to save my file in `image` folder which I already create in my `C:/python` folder. This code save my file in the `Python` folder:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload')
def load_file():
return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
   f = request.files['file']
   f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
   return 'file uploaded successfully'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug = True)
```

html code

```
  <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" 
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" />
     <input type = "submit"/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request
 from werkzeug import secure_filename

 UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
 ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
 import os, os.path


 APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 UPLOAD_FOLD = '/python/image/'
 UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, UPLOAD_FOLD)
 app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



@app.route('/upload')
def load_file():
return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
  f = request.files['file']   
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
  return 'file uploaded successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the full path where you want to save the file with `os.path.join`. Just read the documentation for `secure_filename`

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename